# After calling foreach I get undefined

Tags: javascript, object

[image]so i have the following problem on the screenshot.
This is what I tried so far, Ive had similar issues before, at the end I always get undefined printed like a couple times, I want to know why and if possible to tell me what am doing wrong, thanks!
I basicly try to make an object and then with the commands to fill the paramenters for that object, if there's all 3 for example the movie has known name, date and director to be printed as an object, and if its missing even 1, to not print anything, more details in the screenshot.

```js
function solve(inputArr) {
  function Movie(name, director, date) {
    this.name = name;
    this.director = director;
    this.date = date;

    this.create = function() {
      return {
        name: this.name,
        director: this.director,
        date: this.date

      }
    }
  }

  function check(commands) {
    let command = commands.split(' ');
    let movie = '';
    let director = '';
    let date = '';

    if (command[0] == 'addMovie') {
      movie += command[1];
    } else if (command[0] == movie && command[1] == 'directedBy') {
      director += command[2];
    } else if (command[0] == movie && command[1] == 'onDate') {
      date += command[2];
    } else if (movie != '' && director != '' && date != '') {
      return new Movie(movie, director, date);
    }

  }

  inputArr.forEach(element => {
    console.log(check(element));
  });

}

solve([
  'addMovie Fast and Furious',
  'addMovie Godfather',
  'Inception directedBy Christopher Nolan',
  'Godfather directedBy Francis Ford Coppola',
  'Godfather onDate 29.07.2018',
  'Fast and Furious onDate 30.07.2018',
  'Batman onDate 01.08.2018',
  'Fast and Furious directedBy Rob Cohen'
])
```

Comment: `check` does not return anything in most cases. Where is there a foreach?

Comment: I do not think the last `else if` is supposed to be an `else if`

Comment: I can already see that, I am asking why

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). 1. You do not HAVE a screenshot 2. We do not care how long it took you, please cut down the narrative to relevant details. 3. you do not have a forEach in the code

Comment: no foreach in the code and u mention it in the title -1

Comment: Why? Because if/else if will only go into one of the checks, it will not hit every single one.

Comment: @mplungjan is it fine edited now ?

Comment: @EugenSunic added it, my bad!

Comment: You for sure need to remove the else from `else if (movie != '' && director != '' && date != '') { return new Movie(movie, director, date); }
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I see several issues with the code, and I propose a solution

#### Conceptual and complexity

I think the code is over-complicated, in that it aims to create a sophisticated object instance for each movie. You could create a single Object to store all the movies.

#### Using an array rather than a dictionary/hashmap/object to store the various movies

Currently you have to search through the entire array to look for each movies. You are not searching correctly, from what I see: you are scanning over the lines of input but not over the entries in your `movies` array.

I would suggest making `movies` an object, so you don't have to search for a movie: you can use the movie name as the key.

#### I think there is confusion between a 'command' and an array of commands

What is being passed to your function `check` is not really a *series of commands*, but a single command. I suggest calling the array `commands` and a single command `command`. This reduces bugs.

#### You are using split(' ') to split the name from the 'directedBy' etc.

However the movie name may contain a space. Either have quotations around the movie name, which you can't enforce, because the question has forced a format upon you.

Or use another method, such as splitting by ' directedBy '. Obviously this will be broken if the film's name itself contains a ' directedBy '! If you want to block that breakage too, you may wish to search for the *last* `directedBy` in the string, and use that one.

#### Proposed solution

```js
function solve(commands) {
  const movies = {};

  commands.forEach((command) => {
    if (command.slice(0, 9) === "addMovie ") {
      const name = command.slice(9);
      movies[name] = {
        name: name
      };
    }

    if (command.indexOf(" directedBy ") > -1) {
      const [name, director] = command.split(" directedBy ");
      if (movies[name]) {
        // This will only be true if an 'addMovie' has added this key to 'movies'.
        movies[name].director = director;
      }
    }

    if (command.indexOf(" onDate ") > -1) {
      const [name, date] = command.split(" onDate ");
      if (movies[name]) {
        movies[name].date = date;
      }
    }
  });


  console.log("The movies object contains:", movies);
  Object.keys(movies).forEach(name => {
    const movie = movies[name];
    if (movie && movie.director && movie.date) {
      console.log(movie)
    }
  })
}

solve([
  "addMovie Fast and Furious",
  "addMovie Godfather",
  "Inception directedBy Christopher Nolan",
  "Godfather directedBy Francis Ford Coppola",
  "Godfather onDate 29.07.2018",
  "Fast and Furious onDate 30.07.2018",
  "Batman onDate 01.08.2018",
  "Fast and Furious directedBy Rob Cohen",
]);
```

The output you get is:

```
{
  "name": "Fast and Furious",
  "date": "30.07.2018",
  "director": "Rob Cohen"
}

{
  "name": "Godfather",
  "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
  "date": "29.07.2018"
}
```

#### How the last part works

```
Object.keys(movies).forEach(name=>{
    const movie=movies[name];
    if(movie && movie.director && movie.date){
      console.log(movie)
    }
})
```

`movies` is an object. `Object.keys` takes an object and produces an array of the keys of the object. For example,

```
 Object.keys({a:10,b:30})
```

would return

```
 ["a", "b"]
```

In our data format, we have put each film as its own entry in the object, with the film's name as the key. `movies` is therefore this:

```
{
  "Fast and Furious": {
    "name": "Fast and Furious",
    "date": "30.07.2018",
    "director": "Rob Cohen"
  },
  "Godfather": {
    "name": "Godfather",
    "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
    "date": "29.07.2018"
  }
}
```

Therefore `Object.keys(movies)` will return an array:
["Fast and Furious", "Godfather"]

Then we loop through each element of that list. Each element is a movie name. The first time round the loop, `name` is "Fast and Furious".

The next line accesses element "Fast and Furious" of `movies` and makes `movie` point to it.

`movie` therefore points to this object:
{
"name": "Fast and Furious",
"date": "30.07.2018",
"director": "Rob Cohen"
}

From here, it is quite simple. Just print the object!

You have a requirement to only print if the date and the director are present, hence the `if` statement. There is no need to check if the name is present, since if there was no name, there would have been no entry inserted for that movie in the `movies` object.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the detailed answer, it really helped a lot. I want to ask you one thing, if you have the time ofcourse, i want you to explain me the last part of the code, because i kinda got confused there, everything else is crystal clear:  Object.keys(movies).forEach(name=>{
    const movie=movies[name];
    if(movie && movie.director && movie.date){
      console.log({name:name, ...movie})
    }

Comment: Sure! Thanks for marking as correct. I will put an explanation of that last part in the answer, in a moment.